# Is the Universe infinite?

Tags: observational-astronomy, astrophysics, cosmology, universe

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe

Is the Universe infinite or finite ?

Comment: nobody knows.  There are lots of other questions regarding this.  Have you done any prior research. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/38619/what-is-the-shape-of-universe?rq=1 https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11388/what-does-stephen-hawking-mean-by-an-infinite-universe?rq=1  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/if-the-universe-is-infinite-why-isnt-it-of-infinite-density?rq=1

Comment: Latest results looks like it is infinite, but no one knows. If it is finite, and it has a spherical topology, then its radius must be at least 300billion light years: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/88786/32426